# @Mapper(componentModel = "spring" ) of MapStruc lib for automatic interface impl error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mapstruct

I am using MapStruc lib to provide impl to interface everything seems right but still getting error like Description:

Parameter 3 of constructor in com.myspring.RedditCLone.service.CommentService required a bean of type 'com.myspring.RedditCLone.mapper.CommentMapper' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.myspring.RedditCLone.mapper.CommentMapper' in your configuration.
I have one more mapping with same annotation that is working fine but for this class it is giving error .
CommentMapper.java Interface

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring" )
public interface CommentMapper {
@Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "text", source = "commentsDto.text")
@Mapping(target = "createdDate", expression = "java(java.time.Instant.now())")
@Mapping(target = "post", source = "post")
@Mapping(target = "user", source = "user")
Comment map(CommentsDto commentsDto, Post post, User user);

@Mapping(target = "postId", expression = "java(comment.getPost().getPostId())")
@Mapping(target = "userName", expression = "java(comment.getUser().getUsername())")
CommentsDto mapToDto(Comment comment);
}
```

CommentsDto.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CommentsDto {
private Long id;
private Long postId;
private Instant createdDate;
private String text;
private String userName;
}
```

Comment: Do a complete clean and rebuild.

Comment: check if the implementation is generated and on your class path. The implementation probably has the name `CommentMapperImpl`